# PHP $_POST not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am using this jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#message").hide();
    $("#please_wait_box").hide();
    $("#editcustomer").submit(function (e) {
        $("#message").hide();
        $("#please_wait_box").show();
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $("#editcustomer").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "editcustomer_go.php",
            cache: false,
            data: dataString,
            success: function (res) {
                $("#please_wait_box").hide();
                $("#message").html(res);
                $('#message').fadeIn('slow');
                if (res.indexOf("success") != -1) {
                    window.location.href = res.substr(8);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

to submit forms without changing the page.

then the `editcustomer_go.php` echoed results display in:

```
<div id="message" class="messagebox"></div>
<div id="please_wait_box" class="messagebox">Please Wait...</div>
```

i am using tinymce for text editors - its working okay but when the data is posted in the PHP, its not seeing the changed data in the tinymce text editor - it has to be plain text.

how can i get round this?

Comment: Can you explain `its not seeing the changed data in the tinymce text editor - it has to be plain text.`?

Comment: For smaller things like mail you use $_POST. If it's getting heavier it's better to use $_DHL.

Comment: The question title confuses me. How does `$_POST` fail to work?

Comment: if i echo $_POST["site info_notes"]; which is the textarea name it displays the old data, not the new data i entered into the textarea

Answer (score 1):

To grab the data from TinyMCE you need to use their getContent() function.

So in your case it'd be

```
// Grab a reference to the editor
var ed = tinyMCE.get('tinymceeditorname');
// Get it's content
var editordata= ed.getContent();
```

... and then just pass editordata along with the rest of the form as the AJAX call data.

Comment: You'd add those two lines inside your `$("#editcustomer").submit()` function. You'd then need to pass editordata to the AJAX call along with the other data you serialized from your form.